# How to get values from Raw Html for in Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

This maybe stupid. But I'm finding problem in it.

I'm working with Django, I have read docs.

But for the forms, there is class. If I use this then a form is generated in the view,

But actually I hardcoded the entire form, I just need to take the values from it.

Like PHP.

How to achieve this, I don't wanna Django to generate my form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If i understand you, this is how you render your form manualy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: when you say hardcoded, do you mean in html? you can just put it in templates and render it like you would with any html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it with something along this line: `request.GET['field_name']`